# Safari download Japanese filename showing encoded string

Tags: download, safari, filenames, cjk

A java web app has a download function, running on Mac Ventura 13.3 of English. Safari(v16.4) uses default encoding Western ISO Latin 1. The browser lists a Japanese file of "Report バリュードライバーステータスダッシュボード1.xlsx". 
Upon downloading I encode the title with ISO-8859-1 and set header of Content-Disposition as "attachment;filename=\"" + title + "\"". 
All other browsers work but Safari showing downloaded filename still encoded, "Report ãããªã¥ã¼ããã©ã¤ããã¼ã¹ãã¼ã¿ã¹ã¿ããã·ã¥ããã¼ãã1.xlsx".
If I encode it with UTF-8, the title looks like not encoded at all and the rendering failed with `java IllegalArgumentException: The Unicode character [ハ] at code point [12,495] cannot be encoded as it is outside the permitted range of 0 to 255`.
Thank you for helping and very appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused, why are you setting ISO-8859-1 when the title _very much_ isn't Latin? Safari is actually doing the right thing here, forcing the bytes into ISO-8859-1 format and giving you what looks like a "weird title" because you forced UTF8 bytes to be interpreted as ISO-8859-1 bytes. If Java is complaining with that error, search for that error and solve _that_ problem instead?

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, Thanks Mike for the response. 
The reason I used  ISO-8859-1 is because CR and FF works, when Response .setCharacterEncoding ("UTF-8") and Content-Disposition filename is set to new String(title.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1"), except Safari.
If I substitute ISO-8859-1 for UTF-8 then all the browsers will get that java error.
Now seems I have to debug into Java and tomcat to find out why

Comment: what I don't understand is it seems to be purely a backend issue (java and tomcat) why related browser ? Same backend code CR, FF and IE work but Safari

Comment: You may need to show some [mcve] in this case